# What is the role of Angular core module?

Tags: angular, directory-structure

I read an [article](https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a) about organizing folders in Angular and the author uses one called `core`, in which he creates the core module and insert only services which will be called once.

Currently, I'm working on a project whereupon I adopted the structure recommended by the [article](https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a). Inside my `core` folder/module I created a module called `api`:

```
\app
  \core
    \api
    ...
  \shared
  ...
```

My question is: as the `api` is a module, I was wondering why not remove it from `core` and put in `app` folder?

```
\app
  \api
  \core
  \shared
  ...
```

Angular itself has `core` module too (where we import `ngModule`, `Injectable`...) and I'd like to know what is its role.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your **CoreModule** contains code that will be used to instantiate your app and load some core functionality.

To get more idea on this read **[`Core Module`](https://frontpills.com/posts/2019/core-shared-modules/#:%7E:text=The%20Core%20Module%20is%20a,in%20the%20application%20can%20use.)**

Comment: Thank you @Sajeetharan. The article you linked was written, "The clearest and most important use of the CoreModule is the place to put your global/HTTP services." So my api module should be inside `core`module.

Comment: should i import core services into feature or shared modules?

Answer (score 3):

Generally **Core module** is used in order to keep all **API** services and other **common** services (like NotificationsService, ConfirmationService, AuthorizationService etc) that you have in your application in the **providers[... ]** section. Then, the **app.module** will use your **core.module** in the **imports** section.

Comment: should i import core services into feature or shared modules?

Comment: Generally no, because services are singleton (one instance) per application.
But, for instance, you can import a service into a separated module (not app.module) if you make sure that you only need it when the module is created -> so the service will be created when the module will be loaded, not when the entire app is created. 

An example could be when you have a lazy loaded module and you included a core service into the providers of that lazy loaded module.
@Omar

Answer (score 1):

This concept is a bit confusing, and I grasp it by reading many posts. To make understanding core module, I like share my idea related to **Core module**.

The main reason for generating `CoreModule` is making `AppModule` a bit leaner.

For example, imagine, some services like `AnalyticService` are provided in `AppModule`, and these services should be instantiated once in whole of your app. To make `AppModule` cleaner, you could generated `CoreModule`and put them into this module.