# Angular: What will happen if a lazy loaded module calls service from another lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular

What will happen if a lazy loaded module calls service from another lazy loaded module?
What will be impact on the performance of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use services like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

then the service will be injected in the root an be available to all components. That way it should not be a problem to share it.

If you however provide it only in a lazy module, this can cause issues. I cannot recommend that

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loades modules are loaded upon navigating to a route.

Once a lazy loaded module is loaded, a child injector in angular DI system is created, and all the providers the lazy loaded module uses (in his providers array/ imports a module which have providers)
Will create a NEW instance of them which is scoped only to this lazy loaded module, regardless if an instance already exists.

Answer:

Therefore if a service is really instantiated by a lazy loaded module, this *instace* will not be availabe to another lazy loaded module.

Example:

Meaning that if lazy loaded module a, imports lazy loaded module b service, lazy loaded module a will create another instance in its own scope , and will not share the instance in lazy loaded module b.

Solution:

The best approach and recommended way of sharing services by angular style guide is using a service module where the services will reside, and simply access that instance in both of your lazy modules.
More info here:
https://angular.io/guide/module-types
Or here :
[What is the role of Angular core module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084853/what-is-the-role-of-angular-core-module)

If you must lazy load the service specificaly(rare IMO), and share the same instance in two different routes, ask yourself if its really two seperated modules or it only should be one lazy module with its service.